# wordpress как при the_post_thumbnail не добавлять атрибуты width and height к img

Tags: wordpress

при выводе Img добавляють атрибуты width and height что не много ламают вёрстку, как можно чтобы приходил оригинал изображения и не добавлялись атрибуты width and height в img

```
<div class="setup__slider js-setup-slick">
                    <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=88' ); ?>
                    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="setup__item" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'setup__item-img' ))?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    else : ?>
                        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: У вас верстка неправильная. Добавление width и height вместе с srcset - благо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'setup__item-img' ))?>
```

можете самостоятельно выводить тег `img`, получая url миниатюры

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('post_thumbnail'); ?>" class="setup__item-img">
```

Comment: подскажите а как прописать чтобы свой класс выводился и конкретный размер на пример w 600 на h 300

Comment: Свой класс просто прописывайте в атрибуте `class`. Если хотите, чтобы WP создавал миниатюры определённого размера, то можете использовать функцию [set_post_thumbnail_size](https://wp-kama.ru/function/set_post_thumbnail_size). Если просто хотите прописать свои размеры для `img`, то можете также указать соответствующие атрибуты или прописать размеры для соответствующего класса в css